# How to build a high concurrent tcp server with a small number of threads

Tags: c, linux, tcp, concurrency

My design is as follows：

Make the receiving socket non-blocking.
Set epoll_wait to timeout 0.
Loop in the main thread to receive clients and judge `epoll_wait`. If an event occurs, create a thread to process I/O operation。

I think this scheme has disadvantages:

1. Too many threads are opened. Although it can be managed by a thread pool, it seems that a large number of threads need to be opened to handle concurrency.
2. Use queues to manage read and write tasks, Only a small number of threads are required to process queued tasks. But this may cause server delays.

I have an idea:
The task is handed over to the linux kernel through `aio_read` and `aio_write`. This seems to reduce the number of server threads, but I'm not sure if this is potentially risky.

My unused knowledge:
No multi-process programming is used in the server.

Thanks to everyone who suggested.

Comment: "if an event occurs, create a thread" - this will be sure to kill performance. It's better to pre-spawn worker threads, each with a number of sockets they control.

Comment: You can wait on multiple sockets with `epoll`! Just add the further sockets, then if socket 0 got polled a new client waits for being accepted, otherwise an old client waits for communication being handled...